# How to render UI using php and angular for display and in place update

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

```
<?php

    $ach_json = json_decode ( $ach, true );

    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $ach_json ); $i ++) {
        echo "<ng:switch on='edit'>";

        echo "<div ng:switch-when='true'>";

        $title = $ach_json [$i] ['title'];
        echo "<h3>title $title</h3><br>";
        echo "<input type='image' src='http:'..'  name='edit' value='$i' ng-click='editClick()'>";   
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div ng:switch-when='false'>";
        echo "Title: <input type='text' ng-model='title' value=$title> <br>";
        echo "<button ng-click='updateRequest()'>update</button>";
        echo "</ng:switch>";
    }
?>
</form>
```

here I display title, when someone clicks on edit button, I change it to textbox and give the user to update . once someone clicks on update , now I will make a rest call  and need to show updated title.

Comment: Why are you rendering the html with the value already set instead of passing the values in a javascript object and rendering with angular?

Comment: `<script>
  angular.module('app').constant('$ach_json', <?= json_decode ( $ach, true ) ?>);
 </script>` 
should I do something like this

Comment: Did you try to do it without PHP?

Comment: You wouldn't want to assign it to a constant since you will be updating it's value, so I would probably do something like `window.whatever_data = JSON.parse('<?php json_encode($ach)?>');` and make sure you are properly escaping single quotes so you don't break the javascript string.  And then access `$window.whatever_data` from your controller/service/factory/etc

Comment: Seems like you are circumventing the value of using Angular. To truly leverage the benefits of Angular (two-way binding, asynchronous behavior, etc.) you might want to think about do the whole thing in pure Angular and just consuming the JSON data in a service or resource.